# How do i shut off auto fill / autocomplete SSMS 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012

In SSMS 2012

when I type "a." SSMS auto populates "ABS."
 When I type "b." SSMS auto fills "basecamp" 
When I type "d." SSMS auto fills "db_accessadmin."
and so on.

This auto fill is terribly frustrating when writing code, especially with joins.   Obviously, there's some "auto complete" type setting beyond typical intellisense I have activated.

Anyone know what SSMS setting I need to change to eliminate the autocomplete feature?  I do want to retain Intellisense where it fills regular field names.  My peers are stumped too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is called IntelliSense, you can turn it on and off from the `Edit` menu (`IntelliSense` -> `Toggle Completion Mode`) or using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> (default) combination or in the settings of SSMS.

You can turn it on or off, there is no way (what I know) to disable only parts of it.

You may want to consider to install an SSMS plugin which replaces IntelliSense, such as

- [RedGate's SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/)
- [Apex's SQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that's it. When I disable Intellisense, those figures still populate.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this.   It appears to be related to  "auto list members" feature.  To disable

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transact-SQL > General

Ensure "auto list members" is unchecked

I found this via some hours of trial and error.